# swift camera edit frame after take photo

Tags: swift, camera, uiimageview, edit, photo

I am always helping with Stack Overflow. I have a question about programming Swift cameras.

My app has the ability to load photos from a camera / photo album and put them into ImageView. At first, I put the image / image into the imageview immediately, but it is difficult to put it in the desired position as it is.

So I pressed the camera shutter button and inserted the editing function. I used the following code:

```
imageController.allowsEditing = true
imageController.showsCameraControls = true
```

However, in this case, only the square white line frame appears in edit mode. Can I set the white line frame size proportionally? And can I capture the photos in that frame?

Please help me. It is very difficult to find a way. Thank you.

Comment: you can't change default crop rect of imagePicker so you should use third party lib for image cropping. there are so many cropping lib on github. [this link](https://github.com/AlexLittlejohn/ALCameraViewController)  might be help you

Comment: Thanks for reply :) I'll try it!